# How to use certain lines in a script?

Tags: bash

a.sh

```
cat in|while read s
do call "$s"
done
```

This needs to be modified so it runs only for arg+n lines.
e.g.: a.sh 5

```
    cat in|while read s
n=10
for lines arg0 through arg0+n
    do call "$s" 
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be faster & cleaner to filter the input down to just the relevant lines before feeding it to the read loop:

```
n=10
start=$1
end=$((start+n))
cat in | sed "${start},${end}!d" | while read s; do
    call "$s"
done
```

Note: printing lines $1 through $1+n lines will actually print n+1 lines (e.g. printing lines 5 through 15 is actually 11 lines). If you want to print n lines starting at $1, use `end=$((start+n-1))`.

Comment: Would cat in | sed "${start},${end}!d" be faster than sed -n $1,+$np in?

Comment: @user93200: I did some quick tests, and it seems to be the same speed.  What would help is replacing the [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html): `sed "${start},${end}!d" <in | ...` (unless, of course, `cat in` is just a placeholder for something less trivial).

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=10
current=0
while read line; do
   current=current+1
   if [ "$current" -gt "$lines" ] then exit 0; fi
   if [ "$current" -gt "$1" ] then call "$line"; fi
done < in
```